# files in Sources folder cannot access the other files' public classes or functions in Xcode playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, xcplayground

For the life of me I cannot find the solution anywhere, so it seems to me it is a Xcode playground bug.

Within the Sources folder, despite me declaring a class as public, when I try to access the class from a separate file (within the Sources folder), compiler will give me an error message that says it cannot find the class in scope.

However, when I run the playground and ignore the message, the program will build and run successfully, and the error message will disappear until I start to modify the code.

Strangely enough, it doesn't happen at in an App project; it only happens in playground.

I've made a simple demonstration using a playground file called "test" and screenshoted what has happened, which you can see in the attached photo below, please advise! Thanks a lot!

Tried solutions include:

1. restart Xcode
2. restart Mac
3. delete Xcode and reinstall Xcode

Cannot find Person class in scope despite it being marked public

[image: cannot find Person class in scope despite it being marked public]

But the Person class is marked as public

[image: the Person class is marked as public]

Code compiles successfully regardless

[image: code compiles successfully regardless]

Error disappear after running the playground, but comes right back as soon as I modify it

[image: error disappear after running the playground, but comes right back as soon as I modify it]

Answer (score 1):

> Strangely enough, it doesn't happen at in an App project; it only happens in playground.

Actually that part is exactly what is *not* strange. App projects are predictable. Playgrounds are the work of the devil and it's easy to make them behave incorrectly.

What you're seeing is certainly a bug, especially because it can't readily be reproduced by others. On my machine, there are no error messages and everything runs fine:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You might try adding `import test_Sources` to the troublesome file, but I can't guarantee it will make a difference. What I *really* recommend is that you avoid playgrounds.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! I'm not sure what the syntax would be for importing as a testable module, would that be "@testable" ? And noted, about playground being a buggy mess... what would be a substitute for playground? For most of the swift books I'm reading require me to use playground, thanks!